# Las etiquetas requeridas del meta, ¿deben estar en español?

Tags: discusión

Creo que lo más correcto es no utilizar términos en Inglés en las etiquetas, menos en meta, a menos que estén muy difundidos o aceptados.

Esto viene por las etiquetas "requeridas" del meta (discusión, soporte, ¿solicitar-característica?, error), que tienen significados "especiales" para el equipo.

De todas maneras los programadores/administradores ya tienen el trabajo de entender los errores y solicitudes hechos en Español, una pequeña traducción adicional no hará mayor diferencia para ellos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hay que crear un sinónimo.

---

Estoy de acuerdo que conviene en español. Es difícil que alguien que no sea frecuente en MSO/MSE sepa de qué se tratan (sepa o no inglés). Pero creo que la mejor forma sería usando un sinónimo, permitiendo los 2, tanto en inglés como en español, mostrando como principal a los de español.

De esa forma:

- Los que están acostrumbrados a los meta en inglés siguen usando lo mismo de siempre, en inglés.
- Un usuario nuevo lo vería en español y entendería más rápido de qué se trata.

Dejemos que cada uno elija el que prefiera.

Comment: Prefiero castellano, pero hay que dar libertad de uso. Los sinónimos evitan la fragmentación en las búsquedas.

Comment: Sí, yo también prefiero en español, personalmente usaría español, pero no quise explayar mucho en eso para poder marcar mejor mi idea, que se pueda usar ambos.

Answer (score 6):

En este caso sí estoy de acuerdo que las etiquetas deben estar en español, ya que no se refiere a nombres o tecnologías específicas sino a términos totalmente traducibles.

Como refrencia nos podemos guiar del [meta de stackoverflow en portugés](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/) que sí tiene las etiquetas traducidas